# how can i configure google photos api for websites which url is of the type: http and not :https

Tags: authentication, http, google-oauth, google-photos, google-photos-api

on my websites i use a plugin "oziogallery" to display the content of albums that are stored in google photos. This plugin works with google-photos-api to obtain the result. i configured the api and oauth2 authentication panels with credentials in google console. by the past it worked even with websites which url is of the type : http://www.monsite.fr.
I had to duplicate this website and make his new url of the type : https://www.monsite1.fr in order that it works now.
Is it possible to configure the google photos api with "javascript origins allowed" and "allowed redirect uris" in order that it works with websites of type : http://mywebsite.fr?

i duplicate the website and make the url of the type : https://www.monsite1.fr in order that it works.
How to proceed in order tht it works for http://monsite.fr?